# JPA @jointable retrieving unwanted subclasses

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa, join

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GDO.NEWS")
public class News implements Serializable, GenericType {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", insertable=true, updatable=false)
    protected Integer id;


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "GDO.NEWS_FILTRO" , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_NEWS") ,
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "ID_FILTRO",  referencedColumnName = "ID_FILTRO")    )               
    private Set<FiltroRegione> filtroRegione;
}
```

With a OneToMany relation to this entity:

```
@Entity
public class FiltroRegione extends AbstractFiltro  {

//... does not matter
}
```

that extends this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GDO.FILTRO")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "CLASSE_FILTRO", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class AbstractFiltro implements java.io.Serializable, GenericType {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_FILTRO", insertable=true, updatable=false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="TIPO_FILTRO") 
    protected String tipoFiltro;

    public AbstractFiltro() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }




}
```

The point is **the @OneToMany association in News entity returns not only the FiltroRegione entities, but entities of all the subclasses of AbstractFiltro** (they share the same database table GDO.FILTRO, but there is a discriminator column).

I think the problem is the @JoinTable, it ignores the discriminator column and just *fetch all the records from the table GDO.FILTRO* if there is a record in the join table GDO.NEWS_FILTRO associating a record from GDO.NEWS with a record from GDO.FILTRO.

Obviously I would like my Set< FiltroRegione > being populated only by FiltroRegione entities, entities stored in GDO.FILTRO with "FiltroRegione" as value of the discriminator column. How can i obtain such behaviour?

I am forced to use OpenJpa 1.x, supporting JPA 1.0 specs

Comment: If you have a row in the join table that references a filtro that is not of type FiltroRegione, then what is incorrect is your data, not Hibernate. Since this table is supposed to materialize the association between a News and a FiltroRegione, it should not contain rows referencing anything other than instances of FiltroRegione. Remove the unwanted rows from the join table.

Comment: Yes I have rows in the Join table GDO.NEWS_FILTRO that reference various types of "filtro". I thought JPA was able to handle the association by using the discriminator column of the GDO.FILTRO table, and return only the filtro records with discriminator column="FiltroRegione" when it was asked for a Set<FiltroRegione>

Comment: No. If you tell JPA that the join table is used to map an association between two entities, it assumes that it does that, and only that. It doesn't try to ignore unrelated rows from this table.